# How to get the id of the checkbox that has just been checked by the user using jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net repeater which binds the memberid to the id of the checkbox wrapped in a fieldcontain of jquery mobile.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="margin: 0px">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkBox"
                    id="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[MemberId]").ToString() %>"
                    class="custom" /><label for="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[MemberId]").ToString() %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[LastName]").ToString() %>,
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[FirstName]").ToString() %></label>                            
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I have this jQuery function:

```
$('input:checkbox[name=chkBox]').change(function () {            
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            //var isChecked = $(this).attr('checked');   
            var isChecked = $('#'+id).is(':checked');      
});
```

How do I get the id of the checkbox that has just been clicked and tell if it is checked or unchecked by the user as the result of the click action? The current code will loop through all of the checkboxes. The click() does not get caught for some reason so I use change().

Thanks,

Comment: What you have will pull the id and isChecked. What is the problem?

Comment: Problem is it loops through all the checkboxes and checks for all the checked checkboxes. It does not tell me which one was clicked.

Comment: I am still not following. If you put `alert('id='+id);` in the function is it alerting the id of all of the checkboxes on the page?

Comment: yes, it alerts once for every checkbox.

Comment: sigh, I had the same name for all the checkboxes that's why it loops through all of them. I gave each checkbox a different name, it works now.

Comment: @EverydayImSeeSharping Yes, the name is an obvious problem. You might want to sum the solution into an answer to your question and then accept it to share with others. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sigh, I had the same name for all the checkboxes that's why it loops through all of them. I gave each checkbox a different name, it works now

Answer (score 0):

```
var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding the click event (or change) to an element will fire the callback function with the context (the this keyword) equal to the element that was the target of the event (ie, whichever checkbox was clicked). I'm using jQuery 1.7, and the click event works fine for me on checkboxes.

I would suggest using a class to differentiate checkboxes you want to monitor rather than a name, since classes are optimized for selection in jQuery's selection engine.

```
$(':checkbox.im_special').click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var id = $this.attr('id');
  var checked = $this.is(':checked');
})
```

Comment: This is basically the same as my code. I have problem  with the click event and jquery mobile even if using class selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:checkbox[name=chkBox]').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

This should alert the checked checkbox when the input is checked, not on uncheck. If you need to change the fired event to 'change' then do so. But I found that it doesn't behave as nicely in IE as 'click' does for cross browser compatibility. Not sure how it behaves in jquery mobile, sorry.

Comment: that's better but it alerts all checked checkboxes not the one just clicked.